# Reactive Extensions - Pumping items from one collection to another

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, system.reactive

I have an IEnumerable collection and want to pump items into another collection at one second itervals. How do I achieve this? There are so many new extension methods. I don't what to use where yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list1.ToObservable() // Convert list1 to Observable
    .Zip(
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), // Zip it with an observable that ticks every second
        (list, timerList) => list // select list1 only
    ).
Subscribe((item) =>
{
    list2.Add(item); // on each tick, add an item to list2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it. I'm not saying it's the most "Rx" way, mind you (my experience with Rx is still somewhat limited).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Delay(this IEnumerable<T> source, int interval)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(interval);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var source = firstCollection.Delay(1000).ToObservable();
source.Subscribe(x => secondCollection.Add(x));
```